# Evento en formulario dinamico

Tags: javascript, eventos

Tengo un formulario creado dinamicamente con jquery. Queria agregarle el evento change al cambiar inputs, y click o submit al boton. Si lo agrego con jquery deberia conectarme primero con el contenedor estatico html y luego indico elemento dinamico y evento

```
$(".app").on("change","#name", ()=> {
    alert("si")
});
```

como seria sintaxis con js vainilla? con addEventListener? No quiero especificar el onChange en el elemento en si, sino que lo tome directo el addevent.

Comment: Usa [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: O también puedes usar `document.getElementById`